# Why can't I use the lilypond environment?

Tags: environments, linux, lilypond

Sorry if this will turn out to be noob-ish, but apparently I can't integrate Lilypond scores into my LaTeX document (well, neither ABC ones, but that's another question).

I have this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}[quote,fragment,staffsize=26]
  c' d' e' f' g'2 g'2
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

When I run `pdflatex`, I got:

```
ERROR: LaTeX Error: Environment lilypond undefined.

--- TeX said ---

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.35 \begin{lilypond}
                     [quote,fragment,staffsize=26]
--- HELP ---
LaTeX has encountered a \begin command for a nonexistent environment.
You probably misspelled the environment name.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm on Arch Linux, and I got these packages installed:

```sh
[alessandro@commodoroII MMDC]$ pacman -Qe | grep texlive
texlive-bibtexextra 2022.63023-1
texlive-core 2022.63035-1
texlive-fontsextra 2022.62977-1
texlive-formatsextra 2022.62529-1
texlive-games 2022.62102-1
texlive-humanities 2022.62929-1
texlive-latexextra 2022.63034-1
texlive-music 2022.62533-1
texlive-pictures 2022.62992-1
texlive-pstricks 2022.62977-1
texlive-publishers 2022.63013-1
texlive-science 2022.62977-1
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need `\usepackage{lyluatex}` and compile with LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. Also you need to have Lilypond itself installed. See the lyluatex [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf) for details.

Comment: Alternatively you can use lilypond-book, see http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/an-example-of-a-musicological-document. The idea there is that you use Lilypond as a preprocessor first, and run LaTeX (for example pdfLaTeX) afterwards.

Comment: And don't forget to install [`lilypond`](http://lilypond.org/).

Comment: Thanks! `lilypond-book` works, but I wonder: does it run `latexmk` under the hood? Do I have to call it multiple times if I have cross references too? lyluatex OTOH doesn't work, the process `lualatex --shell-escape test.tex` never terminates.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do this with [lyluatex](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex): here is the content of `document.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% Lyluatex needs LuaLaTeX, so fonspec here instead of inputenc and fontenc.
% You may put a font package here ("libertine" or "ebgaramond" for example)
% instead of "fontspec", as they depend on it.
\usepackage{fontspec}
% "pass-fonts" ensures coherent fonts (for lyrics) between the document and the scores.
\usepackage[pass-fonts]{lyluatex}

\begin{document}

\begin{lilypond}
  c' d' e' f' g'2 g'2
\end{lilypond}

\end{document}
```

Then compile with `lualatex`:

`lualatex --shell-escape document`

`shell-escape` is required to allow spawning `lilypond` processes. Otherwise, you may add `lilypond` to `shell-restricted` commands, but it is beyond the scope of this small howto.

On Windows with MiKTeX, use LilyPond <= 2.22 till [this bug](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/issues/301) finds anyone to fix it.

[The documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf) lists the options. The best place in case of bugs or questions is [the issue tracker](https://github.com/jperon/lyluatex/issues).